# How do I calculate the mean of subarrays in the broadcast way in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab, vectorization, broadcast

Currently I did it in this way,

```
a = rand(1e6,1);

n = 5;

m = 0;

for ii = 1 : n
   m = m + a(ii:n:end);
end

m = m/n;
```

Can I make it in the broadcast way to be more concise and efficient?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do. Exactly what subarrays do you want to take the mean of?

Comment: @Dan I got a blonde moment.  The problem is naive and simple just as it looks like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the length of `a` to be a multiple of `n`, you could simply reshape `a` to a `2D` matrix with `n` rows and find average/mean along the first dimension, like so -

```
m = mean(reshape(a,n,[]),1)
```

Comment: @Dr.Lee Don't lose it, you would need it!